# C programming expected ";" or "," or ")" before numeric constant

Tags: c

Having issues learning how to use parameters every time I try to use them with defined constants. I receive the expected before numeric constant error this will be a function but I want to make sure it works before hand. if i include the integers in the main it works as expected and returns the desired integer. This function is supposed to ask the user for a response and compare it with  a menu list. the list has three integers 1,2,3. 1,2 should return option not available 3 should  return a valid answer anything else should return invalid. Its purpose is to act as an option  validator so in the main the user enters a number then this function checks it's validity.  in anycase how can i use the defined constants within the function?

```
    #define high 3
    #define low 1
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
    int option;
     printf("--main menu--- \n");
     printf("--New Game(1) \n");
     printf("--load game(2) \n");
     printf("--exit game(3) \n");
     printf("--------------- \n");
     option=validate(low,high);
     printf(" option %d \n",option);
     return 0;
     }
int validate(int high,int low){
    int option,valid;
    do{printf("enter an option! \n");
       scanf("%d",&option);


    if(option < low || option > high){
            printf("Invalid selection! \n");
            option=0;
    if(option < low || option > high){
            printf("Invalid selection! \n");
            option=0;
    }
    if(option >= low && option < high){
            printf("option unavailable \n");
            option=0;
    }
    if(option==high){
            printf("valid selection!");
            valid=option;
            return valid;
    }while(option==0);
    }
```

Comment: Your declaration of the function `main` is invalid. For one thing, `main` should take an argc and argv. and for another, once you've expanded the `#defines`, you've declared it as `int main(int 3, int 1)` which is nonsense.

Comment: main() function does not take arguments as specified. Read a book.

Comment: Your `main` preprocesses to `int main(int 3, int 1)`. Next time you should post which line the error points to.

Comment: Unclear what OP wants with answers that well answer original post's problem.

Comment: You were also missing a semicolon after the assignment                                                                                             `valid = option   in block if(option == high)`

Answer (score 1):

The C standard **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** says :

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a **return type of int** and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined
>   manner.
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   <sup>10) Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as char ** argv, and so on.</sup>

In the light of the above

```
int main(int high, int low)
```

doesn't adhere to what the standard says and it is less likely that your implementation will allow `main` with prototype below

```
int main(int,int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear jn mind, #define is a very simple-minded feature.  It defines the name as the text given and the C preprocessor blindly does a text substitution.  So, in your code,

```
int main(int high, int low){
```

becomes :

```
int main(int 3, int 1){
```

...which doesn't make any sense to the compiler.

You have a second problem as well; main() can't be defined with two int args.  You should read up on [how to define main()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Comment: the actual funtion is called  int valid(int low,int high) like I said I tend to write out main function that do what i want them to do then make them a function. is this horrible practice fora noob like myself?

Comment: @Mike Dobson "is this horrible practice fora noob like myself?:  Yes, as it confuses the code.  `main()` is special.  `valid()` is not.

Comment: thank you will stop using main

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes the complete answer

The bugs in your code are:

1. The cpp (C preprocessor) is replacing your high & low (validate function parameters) to numeric constants 3 & 1.
2. You were missing a semicolon at :

   ```
   if(option==high)
   {
       printf("valid selection!");
       valid = option   // << Here
       return option;
   }
   ```

Comment: but how do i fix the numeric constant expecting error?

Comment: Don’t use `#define`. Just use `static const int low = 1;` and `static const int high = 3;`. Later, when you know how `#define` works, you may use it, but remember it’s dangerous.

Comment: Roland is most def correct. You are the man. But why do they not work as defines?